# Python conditional makes variable becomes unsigned and raise `UnboundLocalError`

Tags: python

So I was writing some conditionals when I started facing this issue. Can someone please explain to me why this code fails to execute? (I simplified the semantics to make it simpler to reproduce)

```
a = 1
b = 2

def run():
  if a < b:
    a = b

run()
```

It raises an `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment`. It seems to happen to the variable being assigned inside the if block so I changed the function to this:

```
def run():
  if a < b:
    b = a
```

And then the message was `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'b' referenced before assignment`.

I am not sure if this is due to scoping but this code works normally:

```
def run():
  print(a)
  print(b)
```

Is there any think I missed from how Python works? If so, sorry for the dumb question but I have been working with Python for more than 4 years and never saw this before.

Tested in `Python 2.7.15rc1` inside WSL and `Python 3.6.4` in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You might miss the knowledge of scope of variables.

```
# Here is the global scope of module

def func():
    # Here is the local scope of function
```

So in your code, to use the variable declared in global scope in local scope, you need to add `global` before calling them under local scope.

```
a = 1
b = 2

def run():
  global a
  if a < b:
    a = b

run()
```

Without the declare the global variable inside local scope, the exception `UnboundLocalError` will appear because you declare another local `a` in a line after comparison: `if a < b`. The syntax check will verify the variable declaration in local scope before the executing the code. Therefore, `b` doesn't need to be global inside local scope, but `a` needs.

Or another way is using `globals()` to call module lever variables. But this way will not change the value of variable in global scope.

```
a = 1
b = 2

def run():
  if globals()['a'] < b:
    a = b  # local scope a = 2

run()
# global scope a = 1
```

Comment: It wasn't me with the down vote on the answer you just deleted, just to be clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `a` and `b` inside the function refer to the variables defined outside the function, you can do this:

```
a = 1
b = 2

def run():
    global a
    global b
    if a < b:
        a = b

run()
```